# on click not working on font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple input with a search icon in its right part.
When I click this icon i simply want to trigger an event, say printing something on the console.

So I have the following HTML :

```
<div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" >
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <button id = "btnSrch" type="submit"/>
        <span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

The icon is in the innermost span tag `<span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"/>`

I simply want to log something on the console when I click this icon.

I tried the following jquery :

```
$('.fa-search').click(function(){
        console.log("dddddd");
    });
```

also this one :

```
$("body").on('click', ".fa-search", function(){

            console.log("dddddd");
        });
```

Can someone help me make this work. I am new to this, but I don't see what am I doing wrong..

Comment: try using `$(document).on('click','.fa-search',function(){})`

Comment: do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @ochi no, I don't.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, but it's also not working

Comment: That HTML structure is invalid. `button` is a block element as well as `span`.

Comment: that is one valid point from @AdamAzad i updated my answer

Comment: Is span a block element?

Comment: Why are you binding the click even to the _icon_ and not the _button itself_, anyway? If you click the button but miss the icon inside it (padding, margin, who knows) it won't fire. Seems weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

> That HTML structure is invalid. button is a block element as well as
>   span
>   as pointed out by @adam in comments ws the real problem
>
> ---

It should work it is simple and straight just make sure you are calling it on `document.ready` or before the `</body>` tag.

```js
$(document).on('click','.fa-search',function(){
console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" >
        <span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"/>

</div>
```

Comment: In case of delegation, there is no need to wait for the DOM to fully load.

Comment: The button was the issue as you clearly showed by removing it.

Comment: yes @Andy and i mentioned in the comments above and updated the answer too

Comment: confirm in 2020 and with fa 5.15.1, this solution works for me.    $(document).on('click', '.fa-edit', function () {
      console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
    });